# How do I list only the custom tasks in a Gradle build file?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have written a gradle build file which several custom tasks. They are all like the following:

```
task runThis(type:JavaExec) {
    doSomething()
}
```

When I enter "gradle tasks" in a terminal, none of the tasks I have written myself are listed. Only the standard list of tasks which appear when I run this command against a new project.

How do I get the tasks to be listed? And is it possible to print ONLY the custom written tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 
`gradle tasks --all` should works, and your customized tasks are in `Other tasks` category.

In intellij, there is a panel called `Gradle projects`.
[image]

---

only the custom tasks:
I write a simple task to do the trick:

```
// run with  `gradle printTasks`
task printTasks << {
    project.tasks.collect {
        task ->
            if (!task.group && task.name !='printTasks') {
                println task.name
            }
    }
}
```